# How to get a string out of a plain text file

Tags: bash, extract

I have a `.txt` file that has a list containing a hash and a password so it looks likes this:

```
00608cbd5037e18593f96995a080a15c:9e:hoboken
00b108d5d2b5baceeb9853b1ad9aa9e5:1c:wVPZ
```

Out of this txt file I need to extract only the passwords and add them in a new text file so that I have a list that would look like this:

```
hoboken 
wVPZ
etc
etc
etc
etc
```

How to do this in `bash`, a scripting language or simply with a text editor?

Comment: It seems your list has 3 informations, not two, if they're separated by `:`. [Here's a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash) that should help you in bash to split the lines in your text file. After that, it's up to you to save if to a new file (can use something like `echo >> /path/file`). Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Given your examples, the following use of `cut` would achieve what you want:

```
cut -f3 -d':' /folder/file >> /folder/result
```

The code above would delete anything before (and including) the second colon `:` on each line, which would work on your case, given your examples. The result is stored on `/folder/result`.

**Edit:** I edited this answer to make it simpler.

Comment: thank you soooo muchk, im learning so much on this community through people like yourself!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use awk to get always last column from your file:

```
awk -F ':' '{print $NF}' file
```

Output:

```
hoboken
wVPZ
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I voted you up. In truth, your answer could be wrong because we don't know if the password is always on the last column -- maybe in some lines we could have an extra final column, so the password would not be retrieved. On the other hand, my answer assumes that the strings before the password will only have a `:` as a delimiter and never on the string itself, which could also be wrong. Ah.. I love real life questions like that, with limited/inadequate information, they are challenging and make you think deeply.

Comment: @JamilSaid: Yes, the question could be clarified. Perhaps the second column is a kind of [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

Answer (score 2):

With sed, to remove the string up to `:`:

```
sed 's/.*://' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `grep`:

```
$ grep -o [^:]*$ file
hoboken
wVPZ
```

- `-o` print only matching part
- `[^:]` anything but `:`
- `*` all matching characters
- `$` end of record

Comment: thank you soooo much, im learning so much on this community through people like yourself! Thank you everybody!!